# postgres query optimisation

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

Hi I am trying to optimize my SQL query and taking help to check SQL plan of my query from explain.depesz.
Here is link https://explain.depesz.com/s/4MiM
for my query plan.
I don't have enough knowledge about query plan.
So can some tell me what should I do in my query to optimize my postgres SQL query.

here is my query.

```
SELECT
    ap.id,
    ap.invoice_generated,
    ap.external_order_id,
    ap.appointment_status,
    ap.invoice_generation_time,
    ap.prior_authorization_code,
    ap.fee_details AS appt_fee_details,
    r.id AS ride_id,
    r.external_leg_id,
    r.leg_no,
    r.ride_status,
    r.ride_category,
    vld.fuse_id,
    org.fee_details,
    org.fee_details,
    rad.mode,
    r.distance,
    st.setting_value AS allow_ride_cost_zero
FROM
    ride_details r
    INNER JOIN appointments ap ON r.appt_id = ap.id
    INNER JOIN ride_additional_details rad ON rad.ride_detail_id = r.id
    INNER JOIN organisations org ON ap.org_id = org.id
    INNER JOIN vendor_lists vl ON vl.ride_id = r.id
        AND vl.status = 'active'
    LEFT JOIN settings st ON st.owner_id = org.market_segment_id
        AND st.owner_type = 'market_segment'
        AND st.setting_name = 'allow_ride_cost_zero'
    INNER JOIN vendor_list_details vld ON vld.ride_id = r.id
        AND vld.vendor_list_id = vl.id
        AND vld.status IS NOT NULL
WHERE
    ap.external_order_id IS NOT NULL
    AND ap.invoice_generated = FALSE;
```

[image]

Comment: You're basically asking us for like a dozen indices.  Short answer: Index all the join columns, so the join happens much faster.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I shared the link of SQL plan

Comment: The query takes 30ms (1/3 of a second) how fast do you need that to be?

Comment: This doesn't like the type of query run more than a few times an hour.  Is 30 ms really too slow?

Comment: Actully this query execution time in prod is more than 1 minute. I don't know why